# HtmlUnit - Error in processing Ajax Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, htmlunit

There is a page that I use htmlUnit that processes a lot of content for div's through Ajax. I've tried everything, but I can't get the new page with the changes after clicking the button.
It seems that code inside the script below didn't work.
$ (document) .ready (function () {
...
});

Please help me. Thank you

Part of my code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_60);
client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

HtmlPage paginaDePesquisaLicitacao = client.getPage("url");
client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5 * 1000);
```

HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) paginaDePesquisaLicitacao.getElementById("licitacaoPesquisaIdentificadorForm");
HtmlTextInput inputNumeroLicitacao = form.getInputByName("numeroLicitacao");

```
    inputNumeroLicitacao.type(login);
    HtmlPage paginaCabecalhoLicitacao = ((HtmlSubmitInput) form.getInputByName("pesquisar")).click();
    client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
    Thread.sleep(10*1000);  
 System.out.println(paginaCabecalhoLicitacao.asXml());
```

Error:

```
ERROR 1364 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.h.j.DefaultJavaScriptErrorListener   : Error during JavaScript execution

com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "$" is not defined. (script in https://www.licitacoes-e.com.br/aop/pesquisar-licitacao.aop?opcao=preencherPesquisarIdentificador from (30, 32) to (34, 10)#31)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:883)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:617)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:534)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:336)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:763)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:739)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:730)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScript(HtmlPage.java:922)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:306)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:396)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:236)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:257)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:792)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:748)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1175)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1115)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:219)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:303)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3146)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2074)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:922)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:438)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:389)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:991)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:246)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:190)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:269)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:160)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:534)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:400)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:317)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:469)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:450)
    at br.com.avengers.vista.services.impl.BotELicitacaoServiceImpl.AnaliseComprasNet(BotELicitacaoServiceImpl.java:148)
    at br.com.avengers.vista.services.impl.BotELicitacaoServiceImpl.buscaClientesComprasNet(BotELicitacaoServiceImpl.java:97)
    at br.com.avengers.vista.services.impl.BotELicitacaoServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4e224117.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:649)
    at br.com.avengers.vista.services.impl.BotELicitacaoServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e07ccf12.buscaClientesComprasNet(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset$$$capture(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "$" is not defined. (script in https://www.licitacoes-e.com.br/aop/pesquisar-licitacao.aop?opcao=preencherPesquisarIdentificador from (30, 32) to (34, 10)#31)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4334)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4312)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:4406)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getNameFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2486)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1511)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:1010)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:111)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:424)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:322)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:123)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$2.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:754)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:868)
    ... 54 common frames omitted
```

Comment: After I updated the version show this error:2020-09-04 12:23:36.851  INFO 2253 --- [pool-2-thread-1] .g.h.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController : Re-synchronized call to https://www.licitacoes-e.com.br/aop/msgs.aop
2020-09-04 12:23:36.903 ERROR 2253 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.h.j.DefaultJavaScriptErrorListener   : Error during JavaScript execution
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking getOffsetHeight
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScrip
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.countMatches(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;C)I

Comment: NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils means you have the wrong version of commóns-lang in your classpath (or a duplicate). Please make sure to update all dependencies also.

Comment: RBRi thanks so much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_60
```

Looks like you are using an old version of HtmlUnit. Please try with the latest one and open an issue on github if you still facing problems.

Comment: First, thanks for answer! I updated the version but doesn't work. I use htmlunit in others pages that work, but this site doesn't work. Maybe can be problem css? Or this "$"?